# Can I remove inline citations while copying Wikipedia texts?

Tags: creative-commons, attribution

Many Wikipedia articles have inline citations [like this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey):

> Honey gets its sweetness from the monosaccharides fructose and
>   glucose, and has about the same relative sweetness as granulated
>   sugar.[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey#cite_note-NHB_carbs-1)[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey#cite_note-Oregon_State_University-2) It has attractive chemical properties for baking and a
>   distinctive flavor that leads some people to prefer it to sugar and
>   other sweeteners.[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey#cite_note-NHB_carbs-1)

I am using articles from Wikipedia in my book and I have already provided credit to the authors by including URLs of the articles. Can I remove these numbers that refer to footnotes? They already exist in the Wikipedia pages and a reader can see the reference on the site itself if he wants. Wikipedia attribution policy ([Reusing Wikipedia content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reusing_Wikipedia_content#Re-use_of_text_under_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike)) says that some external notations should generally be preserved by the re-user. "Should be" doesn't mean "must be", does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the [*CC BY-SA 3.0*](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license under which Wikipedia articles are [licensed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License):

You are allowed to make modifications, because Wikipedia doesn’t use a "no derivatives (ND)" CC license.

The license [requires (in section 3. b.)](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) to denote that changes were made:

> […] clearly label, demarcate or otherwise identify that changes were made to the original Work

So follow all the attribution requirements, make clear that your adaptation is licensed under *CC BY-SA 3.0*, and state something like "The original work has been modified.", or if you want to provide more details, something like "Footnote references from the original work have been removed."